# Cache misses in an infinite loop with no memory references?

Tags: performance, caching, x86

I am just running a while 1 loop and measuring cache miss.

```c
int main() {
   while(1);
}
```

This particular process is tied to one cpu(using taskset) and this cpu is isolated, meaning no other process can get scheduled on the same cpu. Now I start measuring cache performance using `perf` and to my surprise last level cache miss is 42%.

```
22,579      cache-references                                            (20.82%)
8,976      **cache-misses         #   39.754 %** of all cache refs      (20.83%)
4,414      **LLC-load-misses      #   42.74%** of all LL-cache hits
```

I am surprised and I expected zero cache miss as I am not doing any memory operation. Any help/thoughts on this.
cpu: model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v3 @ 2.30GHz

Another experiment I did with giving a nano sleep of .1 milli second and cache miss reduced to less than 1%. I have no clue on whats going on.

Comment: Meaningless code in, meaningless results out.

Comment: I have reasons to do this. I am trying to isolate cache issues in a big piece of code and finally my code turns out to be a tight loop. Now I see that there is a jump in cache miss. So I decided to try one simple while loop and result surprised me.

Comment: #1: You might understand better what's going on by having the compile output asm code. #2 Your example is probably too simple - It will compile to only a handful of instructions that might not even *need to use* the cache - branch prediction will always *know* what to do next without the need to access any memory.

Comment: @tofro I understand that. but does this point to a perf issue?. It will be helpful if you can logically explain why 'perf' is showing this kind of output. also when I add a sleep cache miss is falling less than 1%. Not able to logically digest these outputs.

Comment: If the cache isn't used at all by the largest part of your program (the tight loop which wouldn't produce any 'hits', then), the misses collected through startup will prevail. (Note this is an assumption)

Comment: Are you profiling system-wide while this code runs?  The code itself shouldn't generate any cache misses after it starts up, even if you compile without optimization.  gcc 5.2 for example compiles it to a `.L2: jmp .L2` loop, so there aren't even stack memory refs in the loop, and just one insn of I-cache.  Post your `perf` command line.

Comment: You are getting % *of all cache refs*.  Your main() function has only a single cache ref.  You are *actually* seeing the numbers for the OS overhead of getting the process started and the C runtime library initialization code.  Which is inevitably always going to be poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the perf counters are counting some events from kernel code in interrupt handlers.  perf counter events aren't precise, so you'll get counts attributed to nearby instructions, and I guess for ops still in the pipeline when the kernel code did an `iret`.  Or this may just be fully counting events that happened in kernel context, since it would be expensive to mess with perf-counters on every interrupt.

---

Note that the cache-miss ratio only looks bad if you don't take into account how few cache accesses there are, total:

```
$ perf stat -e cycles,instructions,L1-dcache-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-loads,cache-references,cache-misses  ./infloop

Performance counter stats for './infloop':

 6,177,174,823      cycles                                                        (28.79%)
 6,167,361,425      instructions              #    1.00  insns per cycle          (43.00%)
     1,884,882      L1-dcache-loads                                               (42.93%)
        13,133      LLC-load-misses           #   19.41% of all LL-cache hits     (42.75%)
        67,676      LLC-loads                                                     (28.74%)
       391,004      cache-references                                              (28.50%)
        18,025      cache-misses              #    4.610 % of all cache refs      (28.42%)

   2.604227273 seconds time elapsed
```

Timed on a Conroe Core2Duo E6600 (since I bricked my Intel SnB motherboard with Intel's broken BIOS updates).

`cache-references` and `cache-misses` are "Kernel PMU events", while `LLC-*` and `L1-*` are "Hardware cache events", according to `perf list`.  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: This is correct, when I measure only user space events I get zero. The cache misses are from kernel because of timer interrupts